# Parse text for matching key then grab first set of matching table name rows

Tags: python, text-parsing

Trying to do some reconciliations with some large old flat text files(that are honestly messes). Issue I am have is that I find my matching key, I am trying to grab the first set consecutive of rows with a matching table names and ignoring the rest. How would I read what I need and not the rest? Playing around with breaks but the logic is escaping me.

**Example:** If I was looking for a PK of 101 and table name of drink, from the below list I want to print

**drink 25**
**drink 26**

FlatTextFile.txt 
pk_tbl 23 100 
food 0 0  
drink 0 0
dessert 0 0

pk_tbl 101 
food 0  
drink 25
drink 26
dessert 0
drink 27 
drink 28 
drink 29

pk_tbl 102 
food 0  
drink 0 
drink 0 
drink 0
dessert 0

psuedo code for the example of where I am at essentially

```
        pk_flag = 0
            for row in d:
                if (row[0]= 'drink') and (pk_flag =='1'):
                    print(row)                    
                if (row[0]= 'pk_tbl')and (row[2] =='101'):
                    pk_flag = 1;
                elif (row[0]= 'pk_tbl')and (row[2] !='101'):
                    pk_flag = 0;
```

A little confusing haha, any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_table_data(file_path = 'FlatTextFile.txt', table_keyword = 'pk_tbl', table_num = '101', data_keyword = 'drink'):
    output_ls = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fh:
        table = False
        data = False
        for line in fh.readlines():
            if not len(line.strip()): # Ignoring blank lines
                continue
            row = line.split()
            if not table: # Searching for table keyword and number
                if row[0] == table_keyword and row[1] == table_num:
                    table = True
            else:
                if row[0] == table_keyword: # I'm already at next table
                    break
                if not data: # Searching for data keyword
                    if row[0] == data_keyword:
                        data = True
                        output_ls.append(line)
                else: # Searching for more consecutive data keywords
                    if row[0] == data_keyword:
                        output_ls.append(line)
                    else:
                        break
        return output_ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the patter in the file `FlatTextFile.txt` is stored as:

```
table name
food # (none or one or more)
drink # (none or one or more)
desert # (none or one or more)
(food, drink, desert pattern can repeat for a table)
(blank line)
table name (next table name)
(food, drink, desert pattern in any order)
```

You want to pick the records with `drink` immediately after you find table `pk_tbl 101`. The name of the table can be `pk_tbl` + any string or no string + `101`

With the above assumptions, here's the code to pick the specific drinks from table 101.

```
with open ('FlatTextFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    table = False
    output = []
    line_count = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        x = line.split()
        if {'pk_tbl','101'} <= set(x): #checks if 'pk_tbl' and '101' are in x
            table = True
            continue
        if table and 'drink' in x: #finds values with drinks
            line_count +=1
            output.append(line)
            continue
        if line_count > 0: break #we are past drink in table pk_tbl; stop processing
print (output)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['drink 25', 'drink 26']
```